# ! Missing \endcasename inserted <to be read again> in python generated file from jinja2 template

Tags: pgfplotstable, python

I wanted to automate generation of some PDF files. Those files are basically a few pages long tables with just a header on first page.

I have raw data in `.txt` or `.tab` files - both are tab separated - they come straight as database dumps of some tables.

```
\begin{center}
\noindent HEADER
    \pgfplotstableset{
            begin table=\begin{longtable},
            end table=\end{longtable}
            }
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=tab,
            every head row/.style={before row={\hline\rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}}},
            every even row/.style={before row=\hline},
            every odd row/.style={before row=\hline},
            every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
                display columns/0/.style={
                    string type,
                    column type/.add={|}{},
                    column name=ID
                    },
                display columns/1/.style={
                    string type,
                    column type/.add={|}{},
                    column name=DATA1
                    },
                display columns/2/.style={
                    string type,
                    column type/.add={|}{},
                    column name=DATA2
                    },
                display columns/3/.style={
                    string type,
                    column type/.add={|}{},
                    column name=DATA3
                    },
    ]{123456 data file.txt}
\end{center}
```

this is the snippet of the .tex file generated from jinja2 template, column names, header, and file name are filled in thanks to the script and the template, along with number of columns.

When I try to compile this to PDF I get:

```
!Missing \endcasename inserted.
<to be read again>
            \T1\L
l.72        ]{123456 data file.txt}
                ^^M
```

I've tried retyping the line by hand (which makes no sense from automation perspective), using different string encoding to get the file, and searching other anwsers, but the same error can mean quite a lot of different things in LaTeX.

Comment: what's "123456 data file.txt" supposed to be? if that's a file name, avoid spaces or enclose it in `"`.

Comment: @naphaneal Yes it is a file name. i'll try enclosing it in quotes as soon as i'm able to.

Comment: @naphaneal i've added quotes, tried few different things(changing filename, changing encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI and unicode). Looks like pgfplotstable automatically adds quotes - i've got an error about double quoted file. Replacing spaces with _ produces the same error.

Comment: I'd say you best update you code example to be fully reproducing your error. maybe there's something missing somewhere else.

Comment: @naphaneal honestly i've been trying removing and rewritting every line of that snippet. i've stumbled on solution by sheer luck. Data file in header contained special characters(exactly the letter Ł), which despite being encoded in UTF-8 was being read as ANSI.

Comment: very good. I'd say you'd answer this question by your own. maybe you'd receive credit for the solution.